# How to add custom fields in customer list? (opencart)

Tags: opencart

How can I get custom fields into getList function and add they to customer list in backend of opencart?

the following code is form getForm function

```
// Custom Fields
$this->load->model('customer/custom_field');

$data['custom_fields'] = array();

$custom_fields = $this->model_customer_custom_field->getCustomFields();

$confirmation_info = $this->model_sale_confirmation->getConfirmation($confirmation_id);

foreach ($custom_fields as $custom_field) {
    $data['custom_fields'][] = array(
        'custom_field_id'    => $custom_field['custom_field_id'],
        'custom_field_value' => $this->model_customer_custom_field->getCustomFieldValues($custom_field['custom_field_id']),
        'name'               => $custom_field['name'],
        'value'              => $custom_field['value'],
        'type'               => $custom_field['type'],
        'location'           => $custom_field['location'],
        'sort_order'         => $custom_field['sort_order']
    );
}

$data['download']  = $this->url->link('tool/upload/download', 'user_token=' . $this->session->data['user_token'], true);

if (isset($this->request->post['custom_field'])) {
    $data['confirmation_custom_field'] = $this->request->post['custom_field'];
} elseif (!empty($confirmation_info)) {
    $data['confirmation_custom_field'] = json_decode($confirmation_info['custom_field'], true);
} else {
    $data['confirmation_custom_field'] = array();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Custom field values are stored in Json format in `oc_customer` table `custom_field` column.
So you can get these values in `getList()` function and pass them in customers array like this

```
$data['customers'][] = array(
'account_custom_field'=>json_decode($result['custom_field'], true),
```

Now you need to get the name of the custom fields for displaying in customer list as columns of the table.

```
// Custom Fields
$this->load->model('customer/custom_field');

$data['custom_fields'] = array();

$custom_fields = $this->model_customer_custom_field->getCustomFields();

$confirmation_info = $this->model_sale_confirmation->getConfirmation($confirmation_id);

foreach ($custom_fields as $custom_field) {
    $data['custom_fields'][] = array(
        'custom_field_id'    => $custom_field['custom_field_id'],
        'custom_field_value' => $this->model_customer_custom_field->getCustomFieldValues($custom_field['custom_field_id']),
        'name'               => $custom_field['name'],
        'value'              => $custom_field['value'],
        'type'               => $custom_field['type'],
        'location'           => $custom_field['location'],
        'sort_order'         => $custom_field['sort_order']
    );
}
```

You can create more columns in the table

```
{% for custom_field in custom_fields %}
    <th>{{custom_field.name}}</th>
{% endfor %}
```

In the each customer row you can find the `custom_field` in customer's custom field data by matching `id` of custom field and then displaying the data in that particular column

These array will provide you the column names and then by matching `custom_value_id` from customer JSON Decode custom values you can display ..

```
{% for custom_field in custom__fields %}
    {% if customer.account_custom_field[custom_field.custom_field_id] %} 
            {{customer.account_custom_field[custom_field.custom_field_id]}} 
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

There is some more effort required to display the column matching custom value in the right column so use the hint.